# Access 2013: Filter (by 2 columns) on open report

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am struggling to filter (on a form) based on **two** fields and open the filtered report.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should read:

```
"[Employee ID] = '" & Me![Employee ID].Value "' And [Task] = '" & Me![Task].Value & "'"
```

Comment: Well, then use the expression builder, but you should be able to see, that your original posted where condition cannot make sense.